# Why to my images move sideways when the page renders?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a JQuery based photo gallery with navigation tabs to sort between pages of thumbnails. The functionality is mostly there now but when the page first loads all the images in the tab load a few pixels to the right of their correct position and then shift left. They end in the right place but it looks messy.

I think its because I had to build some active CSS changes into my JQuery code to get the tabs to change properly but I can't figure out where I went in the initial code to fix it. Here is my HTML, CSS and JQuery can anyone see the problem?

**jsFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Cmb9p/

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="page_container">
    <div class="gallery_credit"><h1>Illisia Adams</h1></div>
    <div class="gallery_type"><h1>Gallery 1</h1></div>
    <div class="clear_both"></div>
  <div class="gallery_top"></div>
<div class="gallery_content">
    <div class="sp">
        <div class="tabs">
            <span>Page 1</span>
            <span>Page 2</span>
            <span>Page 3</span>
        </div>
            <div class="gallery_thumbnails">
                <div class="panels">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel_content">
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <div class="clear_both"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel_content">
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <div class="clear_both"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel_content">
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/apartments_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for apartments here"><img src="images/photos/apartments_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="images/photos/acrobats_fullsize.jpg" title="Caption for acrobats goes here"><img src="images/photos/acrobats_thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
                <div class="clear_both"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
            <div class="gallery_preview">
                img
            </div>
            <div class="clear_both"></div>
        <div class="gallery_caption">text</div>
        <div class="clear_both"></div>
        <div class="gallery_preload_area"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery_bottom"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.sp {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.sp .tabs {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 101;
    display: block;
}
.sp .tabs span {
    background-color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sp .tabs span.selected {
    color: #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;

}.sp .gallery_thumbnails {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 277px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.sp .gallery_thumbnails a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 11px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.sp .gallery_thumbnails a:hover {
    border-top-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    border-left-color: #FFF;
}

.sp .gallery_thumbnails a:active {
    border-top-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    border-left-color: #FFF;
}

.sp .gallery_thumbnails a:visited {
    border-top-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    border-left-color: #FFF;
}
.sp .gallery_thumbnails .panel .panel_content {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.sp .gallery_thumbnails .panel .panels{
    position: absolute;
}

.sp .gallery_thumbnails .panel {
    height: 277px;
    position: absolute;
}

.page_container {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 960px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.gallery_credit {
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 425px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.gallery_type {
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.gallery_top {
    background-image: url(../Images/Template/page_top.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 20px;
}

.gallery_content {
    background-image: url(../Images/Template/page_tile.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    text-align: right;
}

.gallery_preview {
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
    height: 377px;
    width: 377px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
a img {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}

.gallery_caption {
    float: left;
    width: 375px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 530px;
}
a.contactlink {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(../Images/Template/link_email.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
p {
    color: #999;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
a.zoom {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(../Images/Template/link_zoom.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.gallery_bottom {
    background-image: url(../Images/Template/page_bottom.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 20px;
}

body {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    color: #FFF;
}

.clear_both {
    line-height: 1px;
    clear: both;
    }

.gallery_preview a {
    display: block;
    height: 375px;
    width: 375px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.gallery_preview a:hover {
    border-top-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    border-left-color: #FFF;
}
.gallery_preview a:visited {
    border-top-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    border-left-color: #FFF;
}
.gallery_preload_area {
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var panelWidth = 0;
var startPanel = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Active Styling */
    $('.sp .tabs').css('display','block');
    $('.sp .gallery_thumbnails .panel').css({'position':'absolute', 'height':'277px'});
    $('.sp .gallery_thumbnails .panels').css({'position':'absolute'});

    window.panelWidth = $('.sp').width();   

    /* Position the panels */
    $('.gallery_thumbnails .panel').each(function(index){
        $(this).css({'width':window.panelWidth+'px','left':(index*window.panelWidth)});
        $('.sp .panels').css('width',(index+1)*window.panelWidth+'px');
    });

    /* Add click events to tabs */
    $('.sp .tabs span').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            changePanels( $(this).index() );
        });
    });

    /* Trigger the starting panel */
    $('.sp .tabs span:nth-child('+window.startPanel+')').trigger('click');

});


function changePanels(newIndex){

    var newPanelPosition = ( window.panelWidth * newIndex ) * -1;
    var newPanelHeight = $('.sp .panel:nth-child('+(newIndex+1)+')').find('.panel_content').height() + 15;

    $('.sp .tabs span').removeClass('selected');
    $('.sp .tabs span:nth-child('+(newIndex+1)+')').addClass('selected');

    $('.sp .panels').animate({left:newPanelPosition},1000);
    $('.sp .panel_container').animate({height:newPanelHeight},1000);

}
```

Comment: Please post a fiddle of this, There is a lot of code to consume.

Comment: Try to avoid js styling and use pure css to make your layout look right without any included js file.